# Apply substitution to the first item returned by grep

Tags: perl, grep, substitution

I have this program

```perl
sub f {                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    return ("A/X", "B/X");                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                            

$x = grep( /X$/, f() ) =~ s/\/X$//r;                                                                                           
print "$x\n";                                                                                                                

($x) = grep( /X$/, f() ) =~ s/\/X$//r;                                                                                         
print "$x\n";                                                                                                                

( ($x) = grep( /X$/, f() ) ) =~ s/\/X$//;                                                                                        
print "$x\n";                                                                                                                

($x) = grep( /X$/, f() );                                                                                                      
$x =~ s/\/X//;                                                                                                               
print "$x\n";
```

The result is

```
2
2
A/X
A
```

The result I want is

```
A
```

but only the last attempt produces it.

In my full program, I want to do this with a single line since I have to do it many times. I want to avoid things like `$x[0]` and `f()` is a much more complex function

How can I do it?

Comment: It's much more readable to use an alternative delimiter for `s///` if the pattern itself contains a slash. A pipe character, for instance: `s|/X$||`

Comment: True. I assume Perl is as liberal as sed regarding the delimiters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my ($x) = map { s{/X$}{}r } grep { /X$/ } f();
```

or

```
my $x = ( grep { /X$/ } f() )[0] =~ s{/X$}{}r;
```

or

```
use List::Util qw( first );

my $x = ( first { /X$/ } f() ) =~ s{/X$}{}r;
```

The first silently sets `$x` to `undef` if `f()` returns nothing, while the other two set `$x` to the empty string with a warning in that situation. The second avoids unnecessary work. The third avoids even more.

---

As an aside, you asked for the equivalent of the following

```
my ($x) = map { s{/X$}{}r } grep { m{X$} } f();
```

But I think you want the following:

```
my ($x) = map { s{/X$}{}r } grep { m{/X$} } f();
```

Let's avoid that duplication to avoid making the mistake again!

```
my ($x) = map { my $s=$_; $s =~ s{/X$}{} ? $s : () } f();
```

or

```
use File::Basename qw( fileparse );

my ($x) = map { my ($fn, $dir_qn) = fileparse($_); $fn eq 'X' ? $dir_qn : () }  f();
```